# Programmatically hide / show android support design TabLayout inside AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tablayout, android-support-design, android-appbarlayout

I want to programmatically hide / show the `TabLayout` in my `AppBarLayout`. Simply setting visibility to `VISIBLE` and `GONE` is not enough, as I want to animate the changes and reclaim the space with my content while the tab retreats and leave the space once the tab is shown back.

Below is the relevant part of my layout XML -

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            style="@style/MainTabLayout">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: To animate the change, just add android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to the parent AppBarLayout. That said, View.GONE should be enough.

Comment: That works seamlessly! Thanks! If you could post it as answer, I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As any `ViewGroup` subclass, `AppBarLayout` allows for automatic animations during the adding/removal of child views. You just need to add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` (default to `false`) in your layout file.

As for reclaiming the space content when the view is gone, all you have to do is use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` rather than `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, because the latter holds the space for the invisible view.